# Ajax data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on the Edit button, it should perform an Ajax request depending on the data attribute.

For example:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
    data-request-type="ajax:get"
    data-request-url="/feature/edit"
>
    Edit
</button>
```

In Ajax success callback, how to define to past success result into custom callback or into selector?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: requestMethod, //from data attribute
    url: requestUrl, //from data attribute
    success: function (data) {

    },
});
```

I am thinking doing:

```
data-request-success-type="callback:functionName"
data-request-success-type="selector:className"
```

Or is there better approach?

Comment: But how would a string with a functionName reference be able to access the function? Can it be done, yes, but depends on the scope for the method.

Comment: Wouldn't putting `functionName()` in success callback work? If not, what is alternative approach.

Comment: Have you tries creating a separate method that accepts a parameter and then bind the onclick event to call that method with said parameter? on the succes callback just execute the parameter (in your case the function)

Comment: not when it is a string.

Comment: `data-success-callback="functionName"` `data-success-selector="selector"` - `var callback = $that.data("success-callback"), selector = $that.data("success-selector"); if (callback) someScope[callback](data); else if (selector) $(selector).html(data);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string